# Datatables, fixed headers is displaying at the bottom of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, datatables

When I try to use fixed headers in datatables it breaks.
I.e I specify my fixed header should be header:

```
 fixedHeader: {
     header: true,
 }
```

But I still end up getting fixed header at the bottom which breaks my layout

[image]

The code for my datatable initialization:

```
    var qhse = function () {


        //
        // Setup module components
        //

        // Basic Datatable examples
        var _componentDatatableBasic = function () {
            if (!$().DataTable) {
                console.warn('Warning - datatables.min.js is not loaded.');
                return;
            }

            //Setting datatable defaults
            $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive:true,
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    width: 100,
                    targets: [8,9,10]
                }],

                colReorder: false,
                dom: '<"datatable-header"fBl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
                language: {
                    search: '<span>Filter:</span> _INPUT_',
                    searchPlaceholder: 'Type to filter...',
                    lengthMenu: '<span>Show:</span> _MENU_',
                    paginate: { 'first': 'First', 'last': 'Last', 'next': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;', 'previous': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;' }
                }
            });


            var table = $('.qhse').DataTable({
                drawCallback: function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({

                        title: setData,
                        html: true,
                        placement: 'right',
                        container: 'body',
                        //data: setData,


                    });
                },
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                //colReorder: {
                //    fixedColumnsLeft: 1
                //},
                stateSave: true,
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,

                },


                keys: {
                    className: 'focus focus-success'
                },

                buttons: {
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'copyHtml5',
                            className: 'btn btn-light',
                            title: 'QHSE Data export',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible :not(.not-export-column)'
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            className: 'btn btn-light',
                            title: 'QHSE Data export',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible :not(.not-export-column)'
                            },

                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                            className: 'btn btn-light',
                            title: 'QHSE Data export',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible :not(.not-export-column)'
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'csvHtml5',
                            className: 'btn btn-light',
                            title: 'QHSE Data export',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible :not(.not-export-column)'
                            },
                        },

                        {
                            extend: 'colvis',
                            text: '<i class="icon-three-bars"></i>',
                            className: 'btn bg-blue btn-icon dropdown-toggle'
                        }
                    ]
                }




            });
            // Adjust columns on window resize
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(window).on('resize', function () {
                    table.columns.adjust();
                });
            }, 100);

        };




        // Select2 for length menu styling
        var _componentSelect2 = function () {
            if (!$().select2) {
                console.warn('Warning - select2.min.js is not loaded.');
                return;
            }

            // Initialize
            $('.dataTables_length select').select2({
                minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
                dropdownAutoWidth: true,
                width: 'auto'
            });
        };


        //
        // Return objects assigned to module
        //

        return {
            init: function () {
                _componentDatatableBasic();
                _componentSelect2();
            }
        }
    }();


    // Initialize module
    // ------------------------------

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        qhse.init();
    });
```

html table code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover qhse">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Sl No
                    </th>
                    @*<th style="width:150px;min-width:150px; max-width:150px;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
          model.First().QHSE_name)
                        </th>*@
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
     model.First().Activity_name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
       model.First().Planned_date)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Target_date)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Actual_date)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Status)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Remarks)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
      model.First().Person_responsible)
                    </th>
                    <th class="not-export-column">Edit</th>
                    <th class="not-export-column">Active Status</th>
                    @if (ViewBag.DeleteFlg != null && ViewBag.DeleteFlg == true)
                    {
                        <th class="not-export-column">Delete </th>
                    }

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), 
    "QHSEPlannerDetails", new { id_qhse = item.id_qhse.ToString() }, new { 
      data_toggle = "popover", data_trigger = "hover", id = item.id_qhse, 
          onclick = "HyperLinkProgressIconFunction()" })



                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Activity_name)

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Planned_date > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001"))
                                {
                                    @item.Planned_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Target_date > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001"))
                                {
                                    @item.Target_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Actual_date > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001"))
                                {
                                    @item.Actual_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                }
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Remarks)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Person_responsible)
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <a href='@Url.Action("QHSEPlannerEdit", "QHSEPlanner", new { id_qhse = item.id_qhse })' title="Edit QHSE Planner" onclick="HyperLinkProgressIconFunction()">
                                    <span class="badge badge-info">Edit</span>
                                </a>
                            <td class="text-center">

                                <a href='@Url.Action("QHSEPlannerActiveStatus", "QHSEPlanner", new { id_qhse = item.id_qhse })' title="Add Active status" onclick="HyperLinkProgressIconFunction()">

                                    <div class="list-icons">

                                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>



                                    </div>

                                </a>
                            </td>
                            @if (ViewBag.DeleteFlg != null && ViewBag.DeleteFlg == true)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @*<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/delete.png")"  />*@
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger" title="Delete QHSE Planner" onclick="DeleteItems(@item.id_qhse)" style="cursor:pointer;">Delete</span>
                                </td>
                            }

                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="10">
                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                <h4 style="color: grey;">No data exists</h4>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

using fixed columns breaks it even more.

Comment: What you can do is remove all the styling from the table (remove the classes) and see if it works then. Start building your way back up to your styled table from there.

Comment: The styles aren't the problem as it works fine on the admin template.
Tried removing it too. No luck! 
Any other ideas ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2kvC3Tw

Creates a table at the bottom, Don't really know why.

Comment: what intrigues me is that you have a position: relative on a table that should be fixed (in your image). Did you place it there or is that a result of the script? Can you compare your code to the working admin template?

Comment: I did just that.  I have fixed the problem.
According to compatibility matrix of datatable, when using multiple plugins some features tend to clash. In the admin template they were used separately where as I combined a lot of  the features together.

Okay so solution is , I re-adjusted or drew the datatable again whenever any of the plugins events are used.
I.e  like ordering the datatable , re draws or re-adjusts datatable. Hiding a column , re draws or re adjusts the datatable. Clicking on pagnation , re draws or re adjusts the datatable.

Thank you @sander for your time!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I can only recommend that you answer your own question on this topic to inform people who experience the same issues as you did.